# JS inheritance via 'factory' - undefined - cannot read property

Tags: javascript, inheritance, merge, prototype

*Edit: This is not a question about how prototype works. The problem was about code ordering. I have included the script below.*

```
function copyPrototype(parent,descendant) {
  var parentProto = Object.create(parent.prototype)
  parentProto.constructor = descendant
  descendant.prototype = parentProto
}

function addBird(_staysWinter) {
  let bird = new Bird (_staysWinter)
  return bird
}

function Bird(_staysWinter)  {
  Animal.call (this, 2)
  this.staysWinter = _staysWinter
}
copyPrototype(Animal, Bird)

Bird.prototype.fly = function () {
  alert ('flying')
}

function Animal (_numLegs) {
  this.numLegs = _numLegs
}
Animal.prototype = {
  walk: function () {
    alert ('walking')
  }
}

fluffy = addBird(0)
fluffy.fly()
fluffy.walk()
```

I am stuck...
Why does the following code snippet ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2bz9muf/7/)) cause:
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fly' of undefined`?

The idea here is that I have many different types of 'animals' (simplified) that all share certain properties. However I do not directly want to instantiate the underlying objects.

Essentially when I place an alert in prototype.fly to output `this`, it returns undefined.

<sub>Begin of edit

In my example I took out the `new` keyword, because I noticed the error in my own code as well (but instantiating bird did not fix it so I undid that change... hey i'm still learning).
The real problem was, as was only spotted by Berg, that I call animal before defining it and this was something I would not have found out using Google because I was under the impression that the order was irrelevant!
 
unfortunately my example was wrong, because I should have invoked bird.walk()
And that only works after reorganising my code.
I wrote a javascript merging tool that recursively browses my js classes and builds js files, that are then merged into main category js files that i can selectively include (bird.js, tiger.js, familytreeGrid.js, tetrisGrid.js etc).
At no point had I realised that the order was important until Bergi helped me out. So this is where the problem in my code comes from:

sequence.</sub>

Here is the javascript files merging script, for those interested.

```
#!/bin/bash
# assumes up-to-date version of Apache is used.
# searches for /js/includes/ dir in the currently enabled website, merges the files into a <directoyname>.js, per #<directoryname> under the main dir. Walks down into subdirs recursively, thus building up a .js file with all the required #subclasses in subdirectories. This allows for sharing generic classes, by placing them higher in the directory structure. 
#Deepest directories names will become the javascript names.
# e.g. js/includes/animals.js
# js/includes/animals/birds.js
# js/includes/birds/sparrow.js
# js/inculdes/animals/insects/beetle.js
#will result in sparrow.js and beetle.js that both include animals.js, sparrow.js also has classes from birds.js
collectfromdir ()
{
local dir=$1
for subdir in $(ls -d ${dir}/*/ 2> /dev/null);do
  collectfromdir "${subdir}"
done
  if (( `ls ${dir}*.work 2> /dev/null|wc -l` ));then
    find ${dir} -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.work"| while read collectedFile
    do 
      (( `ls -l ${dir}*.js 2> /dev/null|wc -l` )) && cat ${dir}*.js >> ${dir}../`basename "$collectedFile"`
      cat $collectedFile >> ${dir}../`basename $collectedFile`
      rm $collectedFile
    done
   else
   upDirFile=${dir%/}.work
   #no workfile, create a file in parent dir with dirname
   (( `ls -l ${dir}*.js 2> /dev/null|wc -l` )) && cat ${dir}*.js >> ./temp.work
   (( `ls -l $upDirFile 2> /dev/null|wc -l` )) && cat $upDirFile >> ./temp.work
   mv ./temp.work $upDirFile 2> /dev/null

  fi
}

CURDIR=$(pwd)
mkdir -p $CURDIR/oldjsfiles

WEBPATH=`grep DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf| cut -d ' ' -f2`
cd $WEBPATH/js/includes

for oldfile in $(ls *.js 2> /dev/null); do
  mv $oldfile $CURDIR/oldjsfiles/${oldfile}.$(date +"%Y%m$d"_`date +"%H%M%S"`)
done

#recursive call
collectfromdir $WEBPATH/js/includes
find $WEBPATH/js/includes -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.work"| while read f
    do
      fnew=`basename $f .work`.js
      mv $f $fnew
      chmod 440 $fnew
    done
```

Comment: You're not invoking the `Bird` constructor with the `new` keyword so `this` never gets set to your new object.

Comment: `function addBird(_staysWinter) { return new Bird (_staysWinter) }`

Comment: @naomik Sounds like an answer, not comment.

Comment: @dfsq then go ahead and add it as an answer. I don't feel like doing a full write up on it

Comment: @naomik Haha, the same, I thought maybe you would do it. Boring question, explained million times.

Comment: Yeah. no one else should waste time on explaining `prototype` basics on SO

Comment: Also, you must not call `copyPrototype(Animal, Bird)` before you assign to `Animal.prototype`

Comment: Thanks Bergi! That was the problem... my code example was wrong - In my 'real' code I am calling bird.walk()..